# Azure Mobile Apps Internationalization

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm currently developing a Xamarin.Forms Mobile Application.
I use Azure with Azure Mobile App Backend to store my data.

For example when a user sign in, i would like to be able to send different error messages on the same method. For example if the username is not found, or if the username is found but doesn't match the password.

I also would like to send those message on the culture used by the client application. How can i achieve that ?

Thank you,
Best regards,

Guillaume

Comment: I don't know much on internals of Azure Mobile App Backend, but isn't it just a case of sending the culture information to the server as part of the back-end API call your doing, so you can then load in an appropriate resource and return the correct language reply?  Alternatively you could just return specific error codes to the client and let it handle the translation there?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether your consuming an `Azure` service or not you can consume resources for internationalization.

There is an article [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/localization/) that goes into some depth of how to do this that will be of use to you.

Comment: Hi Pete, thank you for your answer.
My question is about Internationalization in Azure Mobile Apps, not on Xamarin.Forms Apps (I use Internationalization with success in my mobile app). I want to be able to return internationalized messages from my azure mobile app backend to my Xamarin.Forms app.

Comment: @GuillaumeLujan Ok - i misunderstood where about your trying to do things.  It may help to update the question with more details so someone else can better answer your needs?